# encodeWithSelector vs encodeFunctionSignature

Tags: solidity

Could anybody explain the the difference between encodeWithSelector and encodeFunctionSignature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes selector, ...)`: ABI encodes the given arguments. The first argument takes a function selector (when a function is called, the first 4 bytes of calldata specifies which function to call. This 4 bytes is called a function selector) and from the second onward it takes any data type. It returns the encoded data as `bytes`.

`abi.encodeFunctionSignature(functionName)`: encodes the function name to its ABI signature, which are the first 4 bytes of the sha3 hash of the function name including types. It returns the encoded data as `string`.

See:

https://medium.com/@libertylocked/what-are-abi-encoding-functions-in-solidity-0-4-24-c1a90b5ddce8

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html

Comment: I read them multiple times, but still do not get the difference. What is function selector? What difference does it make in type of encoded data it returns?

Comment: If you want to call a function in a smart contract, the smart contract needs to know which function to call. The piece of code that lets the smart contract know which function to call is called the function selector. For example, the function selector of the function signature "transfer(address,uint256)" is 0xa9059cbb, and the function selector of the function signature "transferFrom(address,address,uint256)" is 0x23b872dd. By identifying the function selector 0xa9059cbb, the smart contract knows it needs to call the transfer(address,uint256) function, not transferFrom(address,address,uint256)

Comment: You can get the function selector by hashing the string of the function signature using bytes4(keccak256(bytes(functionSignature)))

Comment: So, it means that you can use both of the methods if you want to call the function, the only difference is the approach. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not understanding what do you mean by both of the methods and call what function?

Comment: Sorry. Both of them return bytecode representation of the function, the difference is that encodeFunctionSignature returns the bytecode as a string. Then, when would you use encodeWithSelector and encodeFunctionSignature?

Comment: Use encodeWithSelector when you know the selector and use encodeFunctionSignature when you know the function name (has to be a string or object).